How to improve (decrease) loading time of checkboxes onto lightning-card lwc component
I have a lwc component called the c-record-card which utilizes the lwc lightning-card component to display records fields on the card - essentially the card represents a SObject record (see below for screen shot reference). This custom card component is housed in a parent custom component which in turn is housed in a grandparent component. I'm passing a boolean flag from the grandparent down to card component that checks if a button has been clicked. If the button is clicked, a checkbox is rendered to the left of the record name so that these cards can be selected. How I'm currently doing this is through an @api decorated boolean flag that exists in the card component and using data binding with lwc conditionals in the card template that checks if the flag is true or false.
I noticed that when I am loading (via lazy loading) thousands of records/cards onto the UI, when I click the button to render the checkboxes on each card, it takes roughly anywhere from 3-10 seconds depending on the number of cards loaded. The time slightly improves when I switch from using lwc conditionals to css rules i.e. display : none to hide the checkbox when the button is not clicked. I understand that the time lag here is due to the checkboxes being rendered on many records, but is there any other best practices I can use to further reduce the time, or is this as good as it gets within the lwc framework?
This is part of the template for the card component using lwc conditionals. The other method is essentially removing the conditionals, having the checkbox always be there but hidden with css until a user clicks the button.
               <template lwc:if={showButton}>
                        <div class={checkboxClass}>
                            <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                                <div class="slds-checkbox">
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="options" id="plan-route-checkbox" aria-describedby="error_01" checked={isCheckboxSelected} onchange={handleChange} title={validationErrorMessage} />
                                    <label class="slds-checkbox__label" for="plan-route-checkbox">
                                        <span class="slds-checkbox_faux"></span>
                                        <span class="slds-form-element__label"></span>
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="slds-col">
                            <a data-id={record.id} onclick={handleNavigation} href="#">{record.name}</a>
                        </div>
                    </template>
                    <template lwc:else>
                        <div class="slds-col">
                            <a data-id={record.id} onclick={handleNavigation} href="#">{record.name}</a>
                        </div>
                    </template>



Are you using Locker Service, or Lightning Web Security? See Enable Lightning Web Security. You may get a considerable boost in performance if you're still on LS.
